# How to initialize a vector of pair of string,string in a c++ class?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, initialization, std-pair

How do I initialize a vector of a pair of strings in a C++ class? I tried several things but none worked out.

```
vector<pair<string,string>> myVec(); //doesn't work
```

Answer (score 13):

There is no need to initialize a vector such a way

```
vector<pair<string,string>> myVec();
```

It is a function declaration with name `myVec`  that does not have parameters and has return type `vector<pair<string,string>>`

It is enough to write simply

```
vector<pair<string,string>> myVec;
```

because in any case you are creating an empty vector.

Or if you want that the vector had some initial values and your compiler supports C++ 2011 then you can also write for example

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> myVec =
{
    { "first", "first" }, { "second", "second" }, { "third", "third" }
};
```

Answer (score 9):

If you use `()` you run into the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). You declared a function `myVec` that takes no arguments, and returns a `vector<pair<string, string>>`

Switch to `{}`

```
vector<pair<string,string>> myVec{};
```

Comment: Or alternatively, no braces at all

Answer (score 3):

Try to use it like this, presently your function `myVec` has no parameters and return `vector<pair<string,string>>`:

```
vector<pair<string,string>> myVec{};
```

or

```
vector<pair<string,string>> myVec;
```